# Existence a group with an infinite Frattini subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be group and $Fix(G)$ to be the set of all elements of $G$ that are fixed by all the automorphisms of $G$.

Do there exist a group such that $Fix(G)$ is infinite?

Thank you.

Comment: Why title to be frattini? the $Fix(G)$ is different with the Frattini subgroup

Comment: If there is an infinite family $\{G_i\}$ of groups with $Fix(G_i)$ non-trivial and $Aut(G_i\times G_j)=Aut(G_i)\times Aut(G_j)$ for $i\neq j$, then $\sum G_i$ should  work. In particular you can look for such a family in finite groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples are constructed in the paper

> A. Caranti, S. Franciosi and F. de Giovanni, Some examples of infinite groups in which each element commutes with its endomorphic images. Group theory, Bressanone, 1986, pp. 9-17, Lecture Notes in Math., 1281, Springer, Berlin, 1987.

You can find the paper [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0078685): only the first two pages are free, but the general idea is explained there.